# How to get user id or specified user only using js

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django

```
class Generalnewssortview(View):
def post(self,request):
    user=request.user
    if request.method == 'POST':
        search_query = request.POST.get('search_query')
        sort_by = request.POST.get('sort_by')
        sort_by2 = request.POST.get('sort_by2')
        user_by = request.POST.get('user_by')
        today = datetime.today()
        year = today.year
        month = today.month
        day = today.day
        print('gen_news user ',user_by)
        print('gen_news sort1 ',sort_by)
        print('gen_news sort2 ',sort_by2)

        # both deos not have values
        if sort_by=='' and sort_by2=='':

            if user_by=='All':    
                data = news_updates.objects.filter(news_title__icontains=search_query,news_created__day=day,news_created__month=month,news_created__year=year,news_catagory='General').order_by('-news_created')
                response_data = []
                for item in data:
                    # print(item.news_created)
                    response_data.append({
                    'image_url': item.news_img.url,
                    'news_title': item.news_title,
                    'news_desc': item.news_desc,
                    'news_created':item.news_created,
                    })
            else:
                data = news_updates.objects.filter(news_title__icontains=search_query,user=user_by,news_created__day=day,news_created__month=month,news_created__year=year,news_catagory='General').order_by('-news_created')
                response_data = []
                for item in data:
                    response_data.append({
                    'image_url': item.news_img.url,
                    'news_title': item.news_title,
                    'news_desc': item.news_desc,
                    'news_created':item.news_created,
                    })
        # both have values
        elif sort_by!='' and sort_by2!='':
            if user_by=='All':
                data = news_updates.objects.filter(news_title__icontains=search_query,news_created__gte=(sort_by),news_created__lte=(sort_by2),news_catagory='General').order_by('-news_created')
                # print(data)
                response_data = []
                for item in data:
                    print(item.news_created)
                    response_data.append({
                    'image_url': item.news_img.url,
                    'news_title': item.news_title,
                    'news_desc': item.news_desc,
                    'news_created':item.news_created,
                    })
            else:
                data = news_updates.objects.filter(news_title__icontains=search_query,user=user_by,news_created__gte=(sort_by),news_created__lte=(sort_by2),news_catagory='General').order_by('-news_created')
                response_data = []
                for item in data:
                    response_data.append({
                    'image_url': item.news_img.url,
                    'news_title': item.news_title,
                    'news_desc': item.news_desc,
                    'news_created':item.news_created,
                    })
        # starting date have value
        elif sort_by!='' and sort_by2=='':
            if user_by=='All':
                data = news_updates.objects.filter(news_title__icontains=search_query,news_created__gte=(sort_by),news_catagory='General').order_by('-news_created')
                # print(data)
                response_data = []
                for item in data:
                    response_data.append({
                    'image_url': item.news_img.url,
                    'news_title': item.news_title,
                    'news_desc': item.news_desc,
                    'news_created':item.news_created,
                    })
            else:
                data = news_updates.objects.filter(news_title__icontains=search_query,user=user_by,news_created__gte=(sort_by),news_catagory='General').order_by('-news_created')
                response_data = []
                for item in data:
                    response_data.append({
                    'image_url': item.news_img.url,
                    'news_title': item.news_title,
                    'news_desc': item.news_desc,
                    'news_created':item.news_created,
                    })
        elif sort_by=='' and sort_by2!='':
            if user_by=='All':
                data = news_updates.objects.filter(news_title__icontains=search_query,news_created__lte=(sort_by2),news_catagory='General').order_by('-news_created')
                # print(data)
                response_data = []
                for item in data:
                    response_data.append({
                    'image_url': item.news_img.url,
                    'news_title': item.news_title,
                    'news_desc': item.news_desc,
                    'news_created':item.news_created,
                    })
            else:
                data = news_updates.objects.filter(news_title__icontains=search_query,user=user_by,news_created__lte=(sort_by2),news_catagory='General').order_by('-news_created')
                response_data = []
                for item in data:
                    response_data.append({
                    'image_url': item.news_img.url,
                    'news_title': item.news_title,
                    'news_desc': item.news_desc,
                    'news_created':item.news_created,
                    })
        return JsonResponse(response_data, safe=False)
```

```js
function fetchData(searchQuery, sortBy,sortBy2,userBy) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/search_sort_data/',
        type: 'POST',
        headers: {
            "X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken")
          },
        data: {
            'search_query': searchQuery,
            'sort_by': sortBy,
            'sort_by2':sortBy2,
            'user_by':userBy
        },
        success: function(data) {
            var cardsContainer = $('#news-container');
            cardsContainer.empty();
            
            $.each(data, function(index, item) {
                var cardHtml = `
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="card">
                            <img src="${item.image_url}" class="card-img-top" alt="News">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title"> ${item.news_title}</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">${item.news_created}</p>
                                <p class="card-text">${item.news_desc}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                `;
                cardsContainer.append(cardHtml);
            });
            if(data==''){
                cardsContainer.append(`<h5>No news to display on this day</h5>`);
            }
        }
    });
}

    fetchData('', '','','All');


$('#search-btn').click(function() {
    var searchQuery = $('#search-input').val();
    var sortBy = $('#date-input').val();
    var sortBy2 = $('#date-input2').val();
    var userBy = $('#user-select').val();
    fetchData(searchQuery,sortBy,sortBy2,userBy);
})

$('#user-select').change(function() {
    var searchQuery = $('#search-input').val();
    var sortBy = $('#date-input').val();
    var sortBy2 = $('#date-input2').val();
    var userBy = $(this).val();
    fetchData(searchQuery,sortBy,sortBy2,userBy);
});


$('#date_submit').click(function() {
    var searchQuery = $('#search-input').val();
    var sortBy = $('#date-input').val();
    var sortBy2 = $('#date-input2').val();
    var userBy = $('#user-select').val();
    fetchData(searchQuery,sortBy,sortBy2,userBy);
});
```

Iam currently using django for a project. In my news page it shows news uploaded by all users, what i need is to put a delete button under each news which is if uploaded by the logged in user,not for every news.(ie,the logged in user can only delete news uploaded by him) Need a condition to check this. Question maybe stupid but expecting a way to do this using js,
above snippet is how i fetch the news,
"by the way iam new to django ;)"

[News page looks somewhat like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPRq1.png)

Comment: Could you perhaps, rephrase your question? Right now it is not that clear.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you include some of the code you have already, a proper solution can be given.
A simple method could be that you put an identifier for the creator user_id on the news card, you can use "data-user" or any other attribute.
Then with javascript as you load the stories, you can check if any of these match the current user id and show the button and all other buttons can be hidden.

Comment: Could you please provide some coding sample files? It'd help us to figure out how to fix that problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

you don't need js to do that you can do it in HTML.
assuming your `News` model has a `User` Foreign key.
and in HTML where you render all the News you can put a condition for the delete button like this:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated and request.user.id == your_queryset_variable_name.user_id %}
<button> Delete </button>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: @Hermal Patel i dont think i can do that bcz the news card is appended using ajax so i think the method you mentioned will only work when page is refreshed, i'll try to put my code here for more clarification

Comment: @sidhusidz nah it will work with ajax too. In ajax call you’re returning html template already. You just have to put a condition there